# How do I use lag function to get my desired df from my source df?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a source dataframe that looks like this  -

| Id | Offset | a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p | 1 | 1 | 2 | null | null | null | null |
| p | 2 | null | null | 3 | 4 | null | null |
| q | 1 | 1 | 2 | null | null | null | null |
| q | 2 | null | null | 3 | 4 | null | null |
| q | 3 | null | null | null | null | 5 | 6 |

You can think of the columns (a-f) to be some features that describe some object (named Id), and these features get updated over time (the offsets). Not all of these features will be updated at the same time. This data is essentially my first df. From this df though, I need to get something like the second df, that essentially describes my objects with all the feature data available at that point of time.

I need my output df to be like this -

| Id | Offset | a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p | 1 | 1 | 2 | n | n | n | n |
| p | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | n | n |
| q | 1 | 1 | 2 | n | n | n | n |
| q | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | n | n |
| q | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

how can I achieve this with lag function (or something else?) in pyspark?

Comment: Do explain the reasoning behind how the values are derived.

Comment: You can think of the columns (a-f) to be some features that describe some object (named Id), and these features get updated over time (the offsets). Not all of these features will be updated at the same time. This data is essentially my first df. From this df though, I need to get something like the second df, that essentially describes my objects with all the feature data available at that point of time.

Comment: if `n` means null, you could simply write null everywhere.... that'd be easier for your readers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the input and the expected output and your explanation, I assume you want to fill for all rows following a row with a non-null value, the value contained in the non-null row.

To do this, you can apply [`last`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.last.html) aggregate over a window and for rows between current and all previous rows while ignoring nulls.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

data = [("p", 1, 1, 2, None, None, None, None,),
        ("p", 2, None, None, 3, 4, None, None,),
        ("q", 1, 1, 2, None, None, None, None,),
        ("q", 2, None, None, 3, 4, None, None,),
        ("q", 3, None, None, None, None, 5, 6,), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Id", "Offset", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f",))

window_spec = W.partitionBy("Id").orderBy(F.asc("Offset")).rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.currentRow)

features_to_transform = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

transformations = [(F.last(feature, ignorenulls=True).over(window_spec)).alias(feature) 
                   for feature in features_to_transform]

df.select("Id", "Offset", *transformations).show()
```

### Output

```
+---+------+---+---+----+----+----+----+
| Id|Offset|  a|  b|   c|   d|   e|   f|
+---+------+---+---+----+----+----+----+
|  p|     1|  1|  2|null|null|null|null|
|  p|     2|  1|  2|   3|   4|null|null|
|  q|     1|  1|  2|null|null|null|null|
|  q|     2|  1|  2|   3|   4|null|null|
|  q|     3|  1|  2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
+---+------+---+---+----+----+----+----+
```